# Excel corrput due to creation of dropdown list with apache-poi library

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

**Need description**

I need to create a dropdown list in Excel with `Apache POI`. This list should contains strings.

**Code**

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(fieldName.getTabName());
XSSFDataValidationHelper helper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) helper.createExplicitListConstraint(myarray);
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(3, 10, 5, 5);
XSSFDataValidation validation = (XSSFDataValidation) helper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
validation.setEmptyCellAllowed(false);
validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

**Error**

For some content it is working fine. But if the array `myarray` contains some values like `STUDENT` or `HOUSE, DEF`, I got an error when I want to open the Excel:

> We found a problem with some content in 'file.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of the workbook, Click Yes.

**Additional information**

`my array` is `List<WebElement>`. I got this list with:

```
Select select = new Select(By.xpath("myxpath"));
List<WebElement> opt = select.getOptions();
myarray = new String[opt.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < opt.size(); i++) 
    myarray[i] = opt.get(i).getText();
```

But I think that this code is not the problem because I'm able to get all options with associated text. It is when I put this content in `createExplicitListConstraint` that something strange happens.

When I print the content of `myarray`, all values are displayed correctly in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limitation of formula length of explicit data validation lists. Max length is 255. If formulas of explicit data validation lists exceed length of 255, then `Excel` fails while opening with error `We found a problem with some content in ...`. If you click `Yes`, `Excel` tells you that it had repaired `/xl/worksheet/sheet*.xml` part. After that the data validation list does not work.

Example to reproduce:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;

class CreateExcelDataValidationExplicitList {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  int arrSize = 50;
  String[] myarray = new String[arrSize+1];

  for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
   myarray[i] = "abcd";
  }

  myarray[arrSize] = "abcde"; // this works
  //myarray[arrSize] = "abcdef"; // this fails

  String arrayFormula = String.join(",", myarray);
System.out.println(arrayFormula.length()); // up to 255 works, bigger lengths fail

  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  DataValidationHelper dvHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
  CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(3, 10, 5, 5);
  DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = dvHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(myarray);

  DataValidation validation = dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
  validation.setEmptyCellAllowed(false);
  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) validation.setShowErrorBox(true);

  sheet.addValidationData(validation);

  FileOutputStream out = null;
  if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelDataValidationExplicitList.xls");
  } else if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelDataValidationExplicitList.xlsx");
  }
  workbook.write(out);
  workbook.close();
  out.close();

 }
}
```

Only solution would be having the list items in cells of a separate sheet and using `createFormulaListConstraint` instead of `createExplicitListConstraint` then. I have shown this here: [Apache POI Double Values in ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108735/apache-poi-double-values-in-combobox/45114880#45114880).

Comment: It will be very difficult ... Is there any way to see Excel logs when you used apache-poi? Indeed, I exactly identified when the problem occurs. But I need more information because values seems to be ok (it is basic string). Because code is executed totally, so the Excel creation is woking fine. The issue is when I want to open it ...

Comment: @Royce: As said my complete example works without any errors in `Excel`. So there is no problem using `String[] myarray = new String[]{"STUDENT", "HOUSE", "DEF"};` as data validation list. If you click `Yes` after the `We found a problem with some content in 'file.xlsx'...` message, `Excel` should tell you what parts of the workbook were removed. Which parts are this?

Comment: Excel not tell me what has been removed. But it is dropdown lists. Indeed, dropdown are not displayed after the click on `Yes`. I checked which values could be a problem. It is `Baron` or `Divorced` or `SELF EMPLOYED DIRECTOR` or `Professional`. Before to add these values in the corresponding validation lists, Excel opens without problem. But it is basic string, that's why I'm understand the problem... And for some others file, same code is working fine.

Comment: @Royce: What exactly happens after you clicked `Yes`?

Comment: The file is loaded but without dropdown lists, and auto column size is not performed.

Comment: I compared the `.xml` of 2 excel files (one ok and one ko). The validation part is the same (except data of course)...

Comment: @Royce: I have a suspicion. There is a limitation of formula lengths. So what legngth do you get from `String arrayFormula = String.join(",", myarray); System.out.println(arrayFormula.length());` when it fails in `Excel` then?

Comment: At the step where it is not possible to open the file I have `154` for the list 1, `51` for the list 2, `155` for the list 3, `290` for the list 4, `41` for the list 5 and `104` for the last one.

Comment: @Royce: 290 is to much length for a formula of explicit data validation list. See my answer now.

Comment: Thank you. So I will try to create as many I need lists in a specific sheet.