# Apache POI - Insert Comma(,) in excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've a String array which I'm trying to insert as a drop down list. As suggested here at Apache POI [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Validation).

One of the element contains comma - `Member, Non-member`

```
String[] arr = {"Group", "Member, Non-member"};
XSSFDataValidationHelper dvHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper((XSSFSheet) sheet);
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dvHelper
                .createExplicitListConstraint(options);
CellRangeAddressList optionAddressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 0, 0);
XSSFDataValidation pickListDataValidation = (XSSFDataValidation) dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint,
                optionAddressList);
        pickListDataValidation.setShowErrorBox(true);
        pickListDataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
        pickListDataValidation.setShowPromptBox(true);
sheet.addValidationData(pickListDataValidation);
```

But what POI is doing, it is splitting the rows into 2 whenever it encounters a comma.
So resultent drop down is:

```
Group
Member
Non-member
```

Please suggest how can I tackle it?

Comment: The inability to include a literal comma in a validation list item is a limitation of Excel rather than POI. You can get around it by using a reference to a range as your validation list. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722398/data-validation-to-include-comma-character).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108735/apache-poi-double-values-in-combobox/45114880#45114880 for solution using `apache poi`